# HERE API - Need to get the coordinates of all route waypoints

Tags: here-api

I need to get the coordinates of all route points through the CURL - in the HERE API documentation, I did not click on how to do it. Tell me what you need to create a request or give a link to the HERE documentation

Comment: Welcome on S.O. You need to put more effort in the question to get answers. What API endpoints are you trying to use, what documentation page(s) have you been through without success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HERE Routing v8 API, you can get the route shape by specifying `return=polyline` in the query parameters, as shown in [this guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/route-polyline.html).

Keep in mind however, that this returns a so-called "flexible polyline", which  is an encoded representation of the route shape coordinates. It looks like this:

```
"polyline": "BGwynmkDu39wZvBtFAA3InfAAvHrdAAvHvbAAoGzF0FnGoGvHsOvRAA8L3NAAkSnVAAoGjIsEzFAAgFvHkDrJAAwHrJoVvb0ezoBAAjInVAA3N_iBAAzJ_Z"
```

You can use a decoder to get the coordinates. Here is [a JS implementation](https://github.com/heremaps/flexible-polyline/blob/master/javascript/index.js) of the decoder. The [heremaps/flexible-polyline](https://github.com/heremaps/flexible-polyline) contains implementations in several other languages.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed.

Comment: Welcome. Consider marking the answer as the solution then, upvote if you found it helpful, and don't skip the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) next time :)